# Using a Bootstrap drop-down menu as opposed to the main menu in responsive view buttons

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu

The default Bootstrap responsive menu collapses into a hamburger button that when clicked drops down to display all main menu items.

However, I would like to include two extra buttons in my responsive menu that when clicked link directly to a **drop-down** menu (not the main menu text but the drop-down menu text).

https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-xft1/v/t1.0-9/11745628_10101301434408019_4057417407621599310_n.jpg?oh=0a5f49c7cb79fe36b7882d24ec9aa560&oe=562320D2

https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-xap1/v/t1.0-9/11760181_10101301434398039_1024527447326664998_n.jpg?oh=b2260a6ac83616e0d92ebb2658a1b8fe&oe=565898DB

I would like the search icon in the responsive menu to drop down to the search field itself not another search icon that then needs to be clicked to view the search field.

You would normally do this by assigning your ul a class of "collapse navbar-collapse nav navbar-nav" and an ID which you link back to in the responsive menu button:

```
<ul class="collapse navbar-collapse nav navbar-nav" id="main-menu"> <!-- Links back to hamburger button on responsive menu -->
    <li class="active"><a href="#">Link <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
    <li class="dropdown">
      <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
        <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
        <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
        <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
        <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
```

But when I try to use the same code for a drop down menu it does not work.

My code for the search menu item at full screen is:

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
 <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">

   <li class="dropdown">
      <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span> <span class="caret"></span></a>        
      <div class="dropdown-menu">
        <form class="navbar-form" role="search">
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Any input would be appreciated!

Comment: You're missing a </li> in your own code example. That won't solve the problem, just thought you should know. Your question is rather vague. Please be a bit more elaborate and concise. What is your problem and what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Not really clear what the specific problem is. WHat does `link to responsive menu` mean? Also What does `override ID` mean?